# OOZIE REST API RERUN - START Job functions don't work

Tags: rest, oozie

OOZIE REST API RERUN - START Job functions don't work

Hi,
  I want to launch a job throw REST API of Oozie (Oozie version 4.0.0 in CDH 5.3.1) but the job doesn't start or rerun.

With ADVANCED REST API of Google I launched:

```
PUT {namenode}:11000/oozie/v1/job/0000001-150528075707705-oozie-oozi-W?action=start
```

the Result is:

`200 OK`

Response does not contain any data.

---

but the job of the workflow doesn't start.

---

Then I tried to launch

```
PUT  {namenode}:11000/oozie/v1/job/0000001-150528075707705-oozie-oozi-W?action=rerun
```

the Result is:

`500 Internal Server Error`

Apache Tomcat/6.0.41 - Error report

## HTTP Status 500 - org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; Premature end of file.

**type** Exception report

**message** org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; Premature end of file.

**description** The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

**exception**

```
java.io.IOException: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; Premature end of file.
    org.apache.oozie.util.XConfiguration.parse(XConfiguration.java:253)
    org.apache.oozie.util.XConfiguration.<init>(XConfiguration.java:63)
    org.apache.oozie.servlet.BaseJobServlet.doPut(BaseJobServlet.java:114)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:730)
    org.apache.oozie.servlet.JsonRestServlet.service(JsonRestServlet.java:287)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820)
    org.apache.oozie.servlet.AuthFilter$2.doFilter(AuthFilter.java:154)
    org.apache.hadoop.security.authentication.server.AuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AuthenticationFilter.java:592)
    org.apache.hadoop.security.authentication.server.AuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AuthenticationFilter.java:555)
    org.apache.oozie.servlet.AuthFilter.doFilter(AuthFilter.java:159)
    org.apache.oozie.servlet.HostnameFilter.doFilter(HostnameFilter.java:84)
```

**root cause**

```
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; Premature end of file.
    org.apache.xerces.parsers.DOMParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    org.apache.xerces.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(Unknown Source)
    javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder.parse(DocumentBuilder.java:121)
    org.apache.oozie.util.XConfiguration.parse(XConfiguration.java:248)
    org.apache.oozie.util.XConfiguration.<init>(XConfiguration.java:63)
    org.apache.oozie.servlet.BaseJobServlet.doPut(BaseJobServlet.java:114)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:730)
    org.apache.oozie.servlet.JsonRestServlet.service(JsonRestServlet.java:287)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820)
    org.apache.oozie.servlet.AuthFilter$2.doFilter(AuthFilter.java:154)
    org.apache.hadoop.security.authentication.server.AuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AuthenticationFilter.java:592)
    org.apache.hadoop.security.authentication.server.AuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AuthenticationFilter.java:555)
    org.apache.oozie.servlet.AuthFilter.doFilter(AuthFilter.java:159)
    org.apache.oozie.servlet.HostnameFilter.doFilter(HostnameFilter.java:84)
```

**note** The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/6.0.41 logs.

#### Apache Tomcat/6.0.41

Code highlighting thanks to Code Mirror

---

The job is on the HDFS and the rest command:

```
GET {namenode}:11000/oozie/v1/job/0000001-150528075707705-oozie-oozi-W?show=info
```

works fine. The answer is:

`200 OK`

```
{
appPath: "hdfs://{namenode}/user/hue/oozie/workspaces/_yarn_-oozie-57-1432735905.63"
acl: null
status: "SUCCEEDED"
createdTime: "Thu, 28 May 2015 15:34:37 GMT"
conf ......
```

What is the simplest way to rerun o start a job associated to workflow in Oozie with API Rest?
With the advices in the official documentation the job doesn't work:

http://archive-primary.cloudera.com/cdh5/cdh/5/oozie-4.0.0-cdh5.3.1/WebServicesAPI.html#Re-Runing_a_Workflow_Job

Thanks in advance.

Sebastiano.

Answer (score 0):

The PUT seems correct for reruns. However it also needs to supply an XML for one of two properties

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><configuration><property> <name>oozie.wf.rerun.failnodes</name> <value>false</value> </property></configuration>
```

or

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><configuration><property> <name>oozie.wf.rerun.skip.nodes</name> <value>,</value> </property></configuration>
```

Those determine which nodes get rerun or skipped.